# How to avoid Hibernate to create foreign key restrictions on oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship, cascade

I have these two entities: Hotel, HotelPhoto

And the following relationship:

Hotel

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="idHotel")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public Set<HotelPhoto> getHotelPhotos() {
    return hotelPhotos;
}
```

When I run this code the hibernate is creating a foreign key restriction with RESTRICT on delete and on update. I would like to have a CASCADE restriction on delete and on update. Is there a way to do that and avoid automatically creating a RESTRICT restriction?